# Sort array with goal to minimize sequence repeat

Tags: arrays, node.js, algorithm, sorting, array-difference

Ok so I have an array of websocket client connections. Imagine that this array contains connections to several different machines. Imagine that each different letter (1,2,3, etc) represents a different host. It might look like this:

```
const conns = [1,1,1,3,3,1,3,2,2,2,2,3,2,1,1,2,2];
```

what I would like to do, is sort the array like so:

```
const conns = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3, ... etc];
```

the rationale is if a client does not respond, I don't want to retry to the same host, I would like to try sending a message to a client on a different host, and only come back to the original host later. This is basically like a round-robin type thing.

I assume the best way to sort the array like this is:

1. find all the different hosts (unique letters) in the array
2. Iterate over this unique list, and splice off items from the original array as I go.

Here is the JS code I have for the above algorithm:

```
const list = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,11,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,1];

const _ = require('lodash');

function findAndRemoveFirstMatch(m, list){
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if(m === list[i]){
            return list.splice(i,1)[0];
        }
    }
}

function getSorted(list){

    const ret = [];

    const set = _.uniqBy(list, function(x){
        return x;
    });

    while(list.length > 0){

        var i = 0;
        while(i < set.length && list.length > 0){
            var item;
            if(item  = findAndRemoveFirstMatch(set[i],list)){
                ret.push(item);
            }
            i++;
        }

    }

    return ret;

}

console.log(getSorted(list));
```

//given the above input, we get:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1 ]
```

I am not proud of this code, and am wondering if there is a better way to do it. The above works for this input, but looking for a good way to clean it up and make it more generic.

Is there a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: Just create a [`Set` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and pass the constructor the initial array.  That will give you an iterable list of all the unique items.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes but does that work with objects instead of primitives? in reality I am using objects not strings. I suppose I could map the objects to primitive id's and then pass that to the set constructor? thanks for good idea

Comment: Yes, a `Set` works with objects.  That's one real advantage of it because it does not need strings as keys.

Comment: I like how the Set description says "If an iterable object is passed, all of its elements will be added to the new Set. null is treated as undefined." that completely contradicts what you just said, and I am believing what you say at this point.

Comment: @jfriend00 well if it works with Objects, how does it determine what makes the object unique? It must use some primitive value? Object.toString()?

Comment: Well, all of it's elements will be added, but there will be no duplicates.  A given key is only ever in a Set once.

Comment: It uses the actual object reference itself.  It doesn't compare to see if the object contains the same properties/values - only whether it's actually the same object reference or not.  Same logic as `objA === objB`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452547/efficient-algorithm-for-ordering-different-types-of-objects/37465720#. The accepted answer (with Javascript code) should work well as long as you don't have a ridiculously large set of machines. My answer is more efficient, but more complicated.

Comment: Thanks Jim, trying to figure out if the problem at hand is the exact same in the link your provided... one difference is that I do not care about wrapping, I only go through my websocket array once, if I am at the end, I stop.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: My algorithm doesn't care about wrapping. As I recall, neither does the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it differently:

- sort input - it will help later
- find maximum count of equal elements (10 in your example, for element=1), *cnt*
- create *cnt* buckets to distribute elements over them
- put elements in sorted order one by one into next bucket with round-robin principle
- merge buckets

This way you get longer series in the end, 1 less than at the beginning.

```
[1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 11, 1, 3, 1, 3]
```

Bad case is when one element appears more than n/2 times, but that's unavoidable.

```
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,11,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,1];
var a = list.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
var cnt = a.reduce(function(res, cur) {
  if (cur == res[0]) 
    return [cur, res[1]+1, Math.max(res[1]+1, res[2])]
  else
    return [cur, 1, Math.max(1, res[2])];
}, [null, 0, 0])[2];

var buckets = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
  buckets[i] = [];

var j = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  buckets[j].push(a[i]);
  j = (j+1)%cnt;
}

var res = buckets.reduce(function(r, cur) {
  return r.concat(cur);
});
```

If you insist on full list of key from beginning, it's also possible:

```
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,11,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,1];
var a = list.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
var cnt = a.reduce(function(res, cur) {
    if (cur == res[0]) 
        return [cur, res[1]+1, Math.max(res[1]+1, res[2])]
    else
        return [cur, 1, Math.max(1, res[2])];
}, [null, 0, 0])[2];

var buckets = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    buckets[i] = [];

var j = 0;
var cur = null;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (cur != a[i]) 
        j = 0;
    buckets[j].push(a[i]);
    j = j+1;
}

var res = buckets.reduce(function(r, cur) {
    return r.concat(cur);
});
```

Comment: I am confused, ideally it should be [1,2,3,4,11,1,2,3,4...] etc?