# How to evenly spread periodic events over time across bins of varying business?

Tags: algorithm

Let us say that we have N bins, and want to trigger `#[n]` events (n < N) on each bin in a given period P in such a way that:

- Events are globally triggered at regular interval: every `P / sum(#[n])`, one event is triggered.
- On each bin individually, events are roughly triggered at regular interval: that is, roughly every `P / #[n]`.

The goal is to compute a single cycle, which will be repeated ad nauseam (for the lifetime of the process). Events should be evenly spread across repetitions of this cycle.

As an example, suppose that we have 3 bins A, B and C such that `#[A] = 5`, `#[B] = 10` and `#[C] = 15`, then a good cycle is probably:

```
[C, B, C, B, C, A,
 C, B, C, B, C, A,
 C, B, C, B, C, A,
 C, B, C, B, C, A,
 C, B, C, B, C, A]
```

It's not clear that this is optimal, though, as the Bs are not evenly spread out.

There is of course no guarantee that the number of events are so nicely distributed; in fact, the number of events could be co-prime.

*Note: an equally good cycle would have switch either column of Bs with the column of As.*

---

Orders of magnitudes:

- A dozen bins at most.
- Up to hundreds of thousands of events per bin.

---

A pragmatic solution is to rely on a randomized algorithm: for the case above put 5 As, 10 Bs, and 15 Cs in a sequence, then random shuffle the sequence. It's not optimal, but has good complexity and a relatively good probability of being relatively spread out.

---

I have a tentative Python solution:

```
def select_minimum(weights):
    n, w = 0, weights[0][1]

    for i in range(len(weights)):
        if weights[i][1] < w:
            n, w = i, weights[i][1]

    return n


def spread_bins(bins):
    total = sum(bins)
    pace = [total * 1.0 / b for b in bins]

    c = [(i, pace[i]) for i in range(len(bins))]

    result = []

    for _ in range(total):
        n = select_minimum(c)

        bin, w = c[n]
        c = c[:n] + c[n+1:] + [(bin, w + pace[bin])]
        c = [(i, w - 1) for i, w in c]

        result.append(bin)

    return result
```

Which seems to work on this particular example, producing:

```
[2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2,
 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2,
 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2,
 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2,
 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

But I am not convinced that (1) it is correct and (2) it's optimal.

---

**How to evenly spread periodic events over time across bins of varying business?**

Comment: I would suggest looking into the [Poisson Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) which is typically used to describe probabilities of events occurring in a certain time. There are Python functions for working with this too.

Comment: Do your evenly spread my apply between the end of a cycle and the begining of the next one ? And do you want a unique cycle repeated infinitely ?

Comment: @Vince: Yes the (single) cycle should repeat and yes the evenly applies across cycles.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37452547/56778. Also see http://blog.mischel.com/2015/03/26/evenly-distributing-items-in-a-list/

Comment: I haven't been able to strictly define what "optimal" is for this problem, and even "correct" is hard to define. As I point out in my blog, there is no perfect solution in the general case, so any solution you come up with will be slightly off.

Comment: @JimMischel: I agree with the "slightly off" bit, however I think that's precisely our measure of optimilaty. The less off the solution is, the better. I would tend to judge solutions based on the sum (or geometric sum) of how "off" the distance between two events in the same bin is. That is, if one computes that for this bin the ideal distance is 3.5 between events, then a solution with distances 3, 4, 4 would probably be better than another with distances 3, 3, 5 (which a geometric sum of the differences would highlight).

Answer (score 3):

Note that your problem is intrinsically equivalent to [Bresenham line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm).

While Bresehham algo distributes two displacement values `dx` and `dy` evenly (as possible) onto `dx+dy` steps, you task requires "more dimensions" - `N = 3..12`

Bresenham algorithm might be extended on 3D case and so on ([example of 3d and 6d](https://sites.google.com/site/proyectosroboticos/bresenham-3d)), but I haven't seen concise generalisation (for example, using priority queues for accumulated errors etc) - perhaps such generalisation does exist. ([some words towards common case](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-algorithm-for-3-d-line-drawing/))

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a data structure for each bin which contains the following:

- Bin size
- A value to reach: used for the calculation, initialized with the sum of all bin sizes
- A current value: initialized to 0
- A growing step: initialized with the bin size

A given bin needs *(value to reach - current value) / growing step* (rounded as integer) steps to appear as next element.

Considering all bins, the next elements will be fired using the *M = min of steps values*.

So we can:

- Update all bins so *current value += M * growing step*
- Keep all bins that have *current value >= value to reach*
- Update the bins we kept above *current value -= value to reach*
- And return these bins as result

This way, we advance in the results in discrete way, without missing frequencies.
Additionally, the order is simply kept because of the order of the initial list.

In *bad* Python that can be:

```
def create_bins( sizes ):
    s = sum(sizes)
    return [[size, s, 0, size] for size in sizes]

def div_rem( x, y ):
    d = (int)(x / y)
    r = x % y
    if r == 0:
        return d
    else:
        return d+1

def next_bins( bins ):
    min_steps = min([div_rem(b[1]-b[2], b[3]) for b in bins])
    for b in bins: b[2] = b[2] + min_steps * b[3]
    result = [b for b in bins if b[2] >= b[1]]
    for b in result: b[2] = b[2] - b[1]
    return result

sizes = [15, 10, 5]

bins = create_bins( sizes )

result = next_bins( bins )
```