# Algorithm to interleave clusters

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to interleave clusters of items onto a 1D array in way that maximizes the spread between items of the same cluster.

Example:

```
clusterA = [A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A]
clusterB = [B, B, B, B]
clusterC = [C, C]

interleaved_example = [A, B, A, C, A, A, B, A, B, A, C, A, B, A]
```

The spread between A values is `(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), mean of ~1.9`

The spread between B values is `(5, 2, 4), mean of ~3.7`

The spread between C values is `(7) = mean of 7`

Mean spread is =~ `2.8`, minimum spread = `1`

Ideally the minimum spread would be optimized first with the mean spread being optimized second.

My first shot at an algorithm is to take the largest cluster and place it in an array, `X`, then take the second largest cluster and insert the values into `X` at positions linearly spaced (rounding as necessary), then repeating for each subsequent smaller cluster, but that's easily demonstrated to be sub optimal, though decent on average.

I've struggled to model this as a convex optimization problem in hopes of using `scipy.optimize.minimize` on it.

I wonder if there are existing principled algorithms that achieve this.

Comment: Isn't the `B` spread (5,2,4)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37452547/56778

Comment: See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29709/8314 and http://blog.mischel.com/2015/03/26/evenly-distributing-items-in-a-list/

Comment: Is the problem restricted to 3 clusters?

Comment: `['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C']` is the optimal arrangement for the example with a total spread of 33

Comment: There is a weird pattern I am seeing for small numbers The maximum optimal value for the total spread is always `3*(n-3)`, where n is the length of the interleaved sequence. Which in turn gives the mean spread as `3.0`. Not sure if this is some kind of upper bound

Comment: Mark Setchell, thanks, the question is now corrected. Akshay not restricted to 3 clusters, and the minimum spread listed there is 1, but since you can't avoid 1 in this example (on purpose) it's a potentially degenerate case as you point out well.  Jim these links look like good answers, thanks for the references!

Comment: One of the most difficult parts of this problem is defining exactly what an "optimal" arrangement is. Every algorithm I've seen produces optimum arrangements on trivial problems, close to "optimal" on others, and arguably "good" arrangements on the rest. But I've not seen an algorithm that provides "optimal" (however you define it) arrangements for all inputs.

Comment: One useful measure is the percentage standard deviation from a perfectly-spaced arrangement. But it's unclear how to rate them. Is it better if the most frequent item has the lowest standard deviation? Or is it better if less-frequent items are more evenly spaced, and the most frequent has a higher variance? Or do we try to reduce the overall percentage variance, regardless of the particular item's frequency.

Comment: By the way, I've also considered modeling this as an n-dimensional [Bresenham line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). `n` in this case would be the number of clusters.

Comment: @JimMischel, your blog post has been invaluable, and after reading through it (and in fact sitting on this question for 2 days myself), I realize how challenging it is to nail down exactly what "optimal" means. I think your mixing liquids analogy and solution is a solid approach that I'm going to implement and play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will get the best spread by inserting progressively at bisecting positions.  Applying this from the smallest to the largest set should result in an optimal spread (or close to it):

First, you need a function that will give you the bisecting insertion points for m source elements in a list of N target elements (where N >= m). The function should start out with the widest possible spread of the first 3 insertions (first, last, middle) and then use bisection from the middle for the rest of the insertion points.

```
def iPoints(N,m):
    d = N//2
    result = [0,N,d]
    if m==N: result[1] = N-1
    while len(result)<m:
        d = max(1,d//2)
        for r in result[2:]:
            for s in [-1,1]:
                p = r+s*d
                if p in result : continue
                result.append(p)
    result = sorted(result[:m])
    result = [ p + sum(p>r for r in result[:i]) for i,p in enumerate(result)]
    return result
```

Using this, you can run through the list of clusters, from largest to smallest and perform the insertions:

```
clusterA  = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"]
clusterB  = ["B", "B", "B", "B"]
clusterC  = ["C", "C"]

clusters  = [clusterA,clusterB,clusterC]
totalSize = sum(map(len,clusters))
order     = -1 if all((totalSize-len(c))//(len(c)-1) for c in clusters) else 1
clusters  = sorted(clusters,key=lambda c: order*(totalSize-len(c))//(len(c)-1))
merged    = clusters[0]
for cluster in clusters[1:]:
    target = cluster.copy()
    source = merged
    if len(source) > len(target):
        source,target = target,source
    indexes = iPoints(len(target),len(source))
    for c,p in zip(source,indexes):
        target.insert(p,c)
    merged  = target

print(merged)

# ['C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

Analysis of this result shows that it is a little better for this set of clusters.  Unfortunately it doesn't always give the optimal solution.

```
from statistics import mean
m = "".join(merged)
spreadA = [ d+1 for d in map(len,m.split("A")[1:-1])]
spreadB = [ d+1 for d in map(len,m.split("B")[1:-1])]
spreadC = [ d+1 for d in map(len,m.split("C")[1:-1])]
print("A",spreadA,mean(spreadA))
print("B",spreadB,mean(spreadB))
print("C",spreadC,mean(spreadC))
print("minimum spread",min(spreadA+spreadB+spreadC))
print("average spread", round(mean(spreadA+spreadB+spreadC), 1))

# A [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1] 1.3
# B [3, 3, 5] 3.7
# C [13] 13
# minimum spread 1
# average spread 3
```

Experimenting with other cluster sizes, I found that the order of cluster processing matters.  The order I used is based on the maximum spread of each cluster.  Ascending if at least one is larger than the rest, descending otherwise.

```
clusterA = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"]
clusterB = ["B", "B", "B", "B"]
clusterC = ["C", "C"]


# ['A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
# A [3, 2, 2, 3] 2.5
# B [2, 2, 2] 2
# C [8] 8
# minimum spread 2
# average spread 3
```

Comment: Average spread is the weighted average, not the average of averages

Comment: Indeed.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, there is a trivial solution for such degenerate cases, where one set has at least half the set plus one element.  That set *must* have two adjacent members, pinning the minimum spread at `1`.

Since your other metric depends only on the total spread of each set (first and last elements), the middle arrangements don't matter.

Put an element of each class at each end of your spread, larger sets outside smaller.

```
ABCAAAAAABBCBA

A spread: 3 1 1 1 1 1 5; mean = 13/7, the same as yours
B spread: 8 1 2;         mean = 11/3, ~3.7 versus your ~3.3
C spread: 9;             mean =  9/1, better than your 7
mean spread (13+11+9) / (7+3+1) = 33/11 = 3, better than your ~2.7
```

---

I recommend that you change your spread metrics to RMS or similar, higher-order computation.  In that case, the cited duplicate should satisfy your needs.