# How to shuffle List<List<string>> without next and previous list having duplicates

Tags: c#, shuffle

So I have couple of lists

```
List<List<string>> fruits = new List<List<string>>();

List<string> apple_small = new List<string>();
apple_small.Add("apple");
apple_small.Add("apple");
List<string> apple_medium = new List<string>();
apple_medium.Add("apple");
apple_medium.Add("apple");
apple_medium.Add("apple");
List<string> apple_big = new List<string>();
apple_big.Add("apple");
apple_big.Add("apple");
apple_big.Add("apple");
apple_big.Add("apple");
List<string> orange_small = new List<string>();
orange_small.Add("orange");
orange_small.Add("orange");
List<string> orange_medium = new List<string>();
orange_medium.Add("orange");
orange_medium.Add("orange");
orange_medium.Add("orange");
List<string> orange_big = new List<string>();
orange_big.Add("orange");
orange_big.Add("orange");
orange_big.Add("orange");
orange_big.Add("orange");
List<string> grape_small = new List<string>();
grape_small.Add("grape");
grape_small.Add("grape");
List<string> grape_medium = new List<string>();
grape_medium.Add("grape");
grape_medium.Add("grape");
grape_medium.Add("grape");
List<string> grape_big = new List<string>();
grape_big.Add("grape");
grape_big.Add("grape");
grape_big.Add("grape");
grape_big.Add("grape");

fruits.Add(apple_small);
fruits.Add(apple_medium);
fruits.Add(apple_big);

fruits.Add(orange_small);
fruits.Add(orange_medium);
fruits.Add(orange_big);

fruits.Add(grape_small);
fruits.Add(grape_medium);
fruits.Add(grape_big);
```

If the list is "apples" the only values it contains are "apples" inside but the number of elements in the list are different. How can I shuffle this so that the end result would be something like this.

```
orange_small
apple_small
orange_big
grape_medium
apple_big
grape_small
orange_medium
apple_medium
grape_big
```

or any other viable combination where the next and previous lists are not being from the same fruit?

Every time the list contains different fruits and number of fruits inside. So if we think of the lists as an array.

[A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3] the shuffle can be anything without repeating the next and previous types. [A1,B1,C3,B2,C2,A2,C1,B1...]

There are cases where the values won't allow the combination to be shuffled in a way where every symbol won't be repeated for example.

[A1,A2,A3,B1] if I have list like that it should be

[A1,B1,A2,B1,A3] It should be able to reuse a list if there is no more options for the shuffle.

Comment: What is the purpose of having multiple apples in the inner list?

Comment: The number of apples in each "apple  list" is different. Oh i see will edit the code, it's not accurate but it should be different number for every list.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: having a list in a list makes things more complicated, and makes a solution more complicated (we have to fetch the first item and take it on faith that all of the others are the same). What is the purpose of the nested list if all the values are the same?

Comment: I mean what's to stop you having `List<Fruit>` where `Fruit` contains the fruit name and the count? Is there a reason why you can't do this?

Comment: The only reason for not having the Fruit class is not changing the main logic of the current program because it outpust the list as shown in the code. But i guess if nothing else comes up it can be changed.

Comment: [Are any answers here suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452547/efficient-algorithm-for-ordering-different-types-of-objects)?

Comment: It's more like if there is an array [1,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,2] to output [0,1,2,1,0,1,2,0,2], shuffle without repeating the previous and next values using all the values.

Comment: If there are no more combinations and there are some lists left but are only duplicates of previous/next lists. Lists that were already used can be duplicated and reused so in the end all lists should be included.

Comment: Isn't that what the answers in the question I linked to are striving to do?: _"That is, we want to make sure that two videos from A will not be placed back to back, if that can be avoided."_

Comment: The answer there shows that it repeat's certain types, and i want every type to be different from the next/previous value. I updated the question a bit showing exmaples .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    public static List<List<string>> ShuffleList(List<List<string>> fruits)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var copy = fruits.ToList();
        var shuffle = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> previous = null;
        while (true)
        {
            var next = GetNext();
            copy.Remove(next);
            shuffle.Add(next);
            previous = next;

            if(!copy.Any()) break;
        }

        return shuffle;

        List<string> GetNext()
        {
            if (previous is null)
            {
                return copy[random.Next(copy.Count)];
            }

            var otherFruits = copy.Where(list => list.Any(f => f != previous[0])).ToList();
            if (otherFruits.Count == 0)
            {
                // start use duplicates if no more unique values
                otherFruits = fruits.Where(list => list.Any(f => f != previous[0])).ToList();
            }
            return otherFruits[random.Next(otherFruits.Count)];
        }
    }
```

Here's the result:

```
foreach (var list in ShuffleList(fruits))
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{list.First()}: {list.Count}");
}

orange: 4
grape: 2
apple: 3
orange: 2
apple: 2
grape: 3
apple: 4
grape: 4
orange: 3
```

If only using all "apples" and one "orange", results will have duplicates:

```
apple: 4
orange: 2
apple: 2
orange: 2
apple: 3
```

Comment: Yes thank you it shuffles it like i wanted. I haven't tested it fully if it will shuflfe correctly if there are not enough values to shuffle but i can work it from there. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't tested this, but what happens if you end up with 3 "apple" lists remaining?

Comment: Just edited it to start using duplicates if for example only 3 "apple" lists remain.